# Sumar un dato dentro de una lista anidada con una condición

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente lista

```
puntos = [[1, 'Dicson'], [1, 'Dicson'], [1, 'Dicson'], [5, 'USER DEMO'], [1, 'USER DEMO']]
```

Necesito sumar el primer dato de cada sublista donde concida el segundo dato

Ejemplo

La suma total para 'Dicson' = 3
La suma total para 'USER DEMO' = 5

He intentado realizarlo con un for pero me sale un error

código:

```
total = 0
for item in puntos: 
  user = item[1]
  if user == item+1:
    total += 1
```

Intente manejar un diccionario pero encontré la limitante de que la llave no se puede duplicar la cual sería el nombre de la persona

Alguna sugerencia para hacerlo con diccionario o una solución para listas anidadas como la tengo actualmente

Comment: Usa un diccionario cuyos valores sean enteros. Antes de meter una llave en el diccionario compruebas si ya existía. De no ser así la metes con valor asociado igual a cero. Después ya simplemente le sumas el valor que corresponda con `diccionario[llave] += valor`. Al final ese diccionario tendrá las sumas separadas para cada usuario

Comment: Justo la suma de cada uno es lo que deseo solucionar :(

Comment: Pero te acabo de decir cómo hacerlo. La suma se va actualizando gracias al `+=` en cada llave.

Comment: gracias, ya lo he pillado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El truco estándar es crear un diccionario con llave nombre y valor la suma del puntaje:

```
puntos = [[1, 'Dicson'], [1, 'Dicson'], [1, 'Dicson'], [5, 'USER DEMO'], [1, 'USER DEMO']]
totales = {}
for valor, nombre in puntos:
    if nombre in totales:
        totales[nombre] += valor
    else:
        totales[nombre] = valor

print(totales)
```

produce:

```
{'Dicson': 3, 'USER DEMO': 6}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: gracias, me quedo claro que puedo utilizar varios iteradores en el for, gracias por el ejemplo